# Save string with single quote in database without mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, string, mysqli

I want to save the string "thats'one" in my table columns, but I don't want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Can anyone guide me regarding how to do that?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `mysqli_real_escap_string`?? What is the reason behind this??

Comment: Where is your insert query code?

Comment: Use parameterized queries. There are many tutorials, threads, and sites already addressing this issue. If you are having a particular issue please post your code.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I know it can possible using `mysqli_real_escap_string` but i want to know is there any other option ?

Comment: @adnankhalid yes, parameterized queries. That is the best practice.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks I'm trying

Comment: Use PDO or prepared statements with mysqli and you'll never have to worry about quotes or escaping chars ever again.

Comment: can you print your query and share here?

Comment: Yes, PDO is the way to go.

Comment: @grimmdude Why? `mysqli` supports parameterized queries just fine.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `PDO or prepared statements` will allow versatility across other dbs but OP also still needs to use parameterized queries. Without those prepared statements are worthless.

Comment: if u dont want to use mysql_escape_string than use addslashes()... I believe you should always use your data provider's escape function instead of addslashes, because addslashes may either do too much or not enough work for the purpose you use it. On the other hand, mysql_real_escape_string knows what to do to prepare a string for embedding it in a query.

Comment: @devpro Yuck, you read the warning on the manuals page for that function right? `To escape database parameters, DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL`...http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: @chris85: :)  lol, yes you are 100% right... he dont want to use it.... dont know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Im seeing so many low quality comments here, here is a rough untested answer.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (Column) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $val1);
$val1 = "thats'one";
$stmt->execute();
```

This presumes `$mysqli` is your connection object.

Additional links on the topic:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)

Comment: That's answer enough explain to insert  `thats'one` without using `mysqli_real_escap_string`